# Quero somar todos os pontos de todos professores e criar um rank com os 3 melhores

Tags: mysql

Gostaria de somar os pontos das aulas de todos os professores e criar um rank com os 3 maiores. Meu problema está sendo em criar a QUERY SQL pra retornar os dados para meus sistema.

Segue imagem do meu banco.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Manda a query que já criou e o retorno dela

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considerando a seguinte tabela, baseada na exibida na pergunta:

```
create table aula (
  `id` int unsigned auto_increment primary key,
  `data` date,
  `titulo` varchar(255),
  `professor_id` int,
  `votos` int,
  `pontos` int,
  `status` int(1)
);
```

Populando a tabela com alguns registros de exemplo:

```
insert into aula (`data`, `titulo`, `professor_id`, `votos`, `pontos`, `status`) values ("2017-04-12", "Aula 1", 3, 8, 33, 0);
insert into aula (`data`, `titulo`, `professor_id`, `votos`, `pontos`, `status`) values ("2017-04-12", "Aula 2", 3, 2, 4, 0);
insert into aula (`data`, `titulo`, `professor_id`, `votos`, `pontos`, `status`) values ("2017-04-12", "Aula 3", 7, 22, 62, 0);
insert into aula (`data`, `titulo`, `professor_id`, `votos`, `pontos`, `status`) values ("2017-04-12", "Aula 4", 7, 2, 7, 0);
insert into aula (`data`, `titulo`, `professor_id`, `votos`, `pontos`, `status`) values ("2017-04-12", "Aula 5", 6, 0, 0, 0);
insert into aula (`data`, `titulo`, `professor_id`, `votos`, `pontos`, `status`) values ("2017-04-12", "Aula 6", 6, 0, 0, 0);
insert into aula (`data`, `titulo`, `professor_id`, `votos`, `pontos`, `status`) values ("2017-04-12", "Aula 7", 8, 0, 1, 0);
```

Você pode buscar os três professores com maior pontuação fazendo:

```
select `id`, `professor_id`, sum(`pontos`) as `total` 
from aula 
group by `professor_id`
order by sum(`pontos`) 
desc limit 3;
```

Ou seja, é selecionado os campos `id`, `professor_id` e o total de pontos baseado na coluna `pontos`. Os registros são agrupados pelo `professor_id`, ordenado conforme a soma de pontos e limitados à três registros. Desta forma, o resultado será:

```
| id | professor_id | total |
|----|--------------|-------|
|  3 |            7 |    69 |
|  1 |            3 |    37 |
|  7 |            8 |     1 |
```

Pode ver o código funcionando [aqui](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c83d5/5).

Comment: Muito obrigado amigo.